# Easiest node to remove from a LinkedList

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

May I know if there is anything like the easiest node to be removed or deleted from a LinkedList.

I know that deleting a node from in between requires a change of the preceding nodes link, whereas deleting from beginning needs a change of pointer to the new head and deleting from the end needs a change of new end of the list.

But, if asked to delete a node from the LinkedList which is easier which of these should be preferred?

Comment: If the node you need to delete is the first node, that may arguably be easier than an intermediate node. But surely there is a *specific* node to delete, not a *preferred* node.

Comment: Is the first node easier than the last node too, or are they of equal complexity?

Comment: In all cases it involves changing the pointer that points to the to the to-be-deleted node. So:you'll need access to that.

Comment: I never came across a problem that deletes the *easiest* data to delete, and not the *actual* data to delete.

Comment: The "easiest" node could have many meanings. A simple approach would be that the easiest should be the fastest. The head of the struct has a complexity of O(1). If your struct has a point to the end of the list, then deleting the first requires the same time as the last. If you have only a pointer to the head, then the fastest would be the head.

Comment: Thankyou @George. That gives a clear answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are on the right track with your thoughts on linked lists. Another thing to consider about removing the *easiest* node from a linked list is the following:

How often will these *easiest* nodes be removed? If the node is removed from the **head** of the list the removal will be **complete in O(1)** time, but if the *easiest* nodes are at the **rear** of the list removal will take a full traversal of the list **completing in O(n)** time.